# How to combine intersection observer with parallax?

Tags: javascript, parallax, intersection-observer

The problem with this parallax is that it runs on all sections of the .parallaxBg class page at the same time.
Therefore, I would like to use the Intersection Observer to run parallax only when the section enters the viewport.

```js
// Parallax -------------------------------------------------------------------------

window.addEventListener("scroll", function parallaxFunction() {
    let bg = document.querySelectorAll(".parallaxBg");

    let distance = window.pageYOffset;
    bg.forEach(parallaxBg => {
        parallaxBg.style.top = distance * -0.2 + "px";
    })
});

// Intersection observer --------------------------------------------------------------

const bgImages = document.querySelectorAll('.parallaxBg');

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    console.log(entries);
    
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        entry.target.parallaxFunction;
    } else {
        entry.target.parallaxFunction;
      }

  });
});

bgImages.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo. Bit late to the party but I needed to figure this out today. Three essential parts to this:

1. Intersection Observer tracks when the `parallax` class is in the viewport.
2. Scroll listener gets triggered when the `parallax` class is in the viewport, and is removed when the `parallax` class leaves the viewport.
3. While the scroll listener is active, we update the transform based on the scroll position

I'm running this through a debounce function to make it slightly smoother, but this is optional.

I think the top position can be calculated better, and I'd be interested to know how we can optimise this, but this answers your question of how to only transform the element when it is in the viewport - you can look in the console and check the dynamically added css inline on the img tag - ONLY when in the viewport :)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        
    var parallaxImages =[].slice.call( 
        document.querySelectorAll(".parallax img")
    )
  
  console.log(parallaxImages);
    
    
    if ("IntersectionObserver" in window && 'IntersectionObserverEntry' in window) {
        
        // Intersection Observer Configuration
        const observerOptions = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px 0px', // important: needs units on all values
            threshold: 0
        };
        
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, observerOptions);
        var el;
        function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
                        
            entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
              el = entry.target;
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax, false);
                } else {
                    window.removeEventListener('scroll', parallax, false);
                }
            });
        }
    
        parallaxImages.forEach(function(parallaxImage) {
            observer.observe(parallaxImage);
        });
        
        var parallax = debounce(function() {
    
            amount = Math.round( window.pageYOffset * 0.2 );
            el.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-'+amount+'px)';
                    
        }, 10);
                
    }

}, false);

/*************************************
  Function: Debounce
  *************************************/
  
  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
          timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
  };
```

```css
/* PARALLAX STYLING */

.parallax {
  height: 40vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* NICE TO HAVE */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

header {
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: steelblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section.spacer {
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: seagreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Scroll down!</h1>
</header>

<main>
  
  <section class="parallax">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="">
  </section>
  <section class="spacer">
    <h1>Keep scrolling!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="parallax">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="">
  </section>
  
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: This helped me solve a similar issue. Thank you Sean!